# Is there a Quick Reference Guide for Progress database code to SQL Server code

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I am tasked with matching functionality that exists in old Progress database files (p, w, I) using TSQL in SQL Server 2012. 
Before digging the Progress web site documentation, I was hoping to find a 'Quick Reference Guide' for lack of a better term, that compares stored procedures, functions, parameters, tables, views, etc.
'def input parameter' is easy enough,  and 'assign' looks like it corresponds with 'SET', but others such as 'no-undo' are not readily understood.
Is anything like this available?

Answer (score 2):

A very long time ago, when printed documentation was still shipped with the product, there was something called "Pocket Progress".

Unfortunately there is no longer any equivalent available.

Also -- it got to be closer to "Backpack Progress".  The last one I have is 7.5" x 9.5" and is very nearly an inch thick -- hardly pocket sized.

NO-UNDO is an attribute of a variable or temp-table that indicates the variable or TT will not have its values undone if a transaction is rolled back.  (This cannot be applied to database tables.) Variables and temp-tables are not shared with other sessions so you do not need to worry about keeping other people's view of them consistent.  By setting them to NO-UNDO you save the overhead of tracking changes to them.  This probably isn't such a big deal now but in the old days that was worth bothering with.  The default is UNDO but most people override that.

The online documentation can be found at: https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2911.openedge-11-7-product-documentation

The "Getting Started" section is right at the top.

Comment: There is no equivalent to those old Pocket Progress booklets still floating around our office, but there is the full (huge) ABL Reference guide, located on the page you linked to. Something like that (along with a PDF reader's search function) is probably what the OP would find most helpful. For example, the index indicates that the `NO-UNDO` option is discussed in the `DEFINE PARAMETER` statement on page 441, the `DEFINE PROPERTY` statement on p. 454, the `DEFINE TEMP-TABLE` statement on p. 491, the `DEFINE VARIABLE` statementon p. 504, and the `DEFINE WORK-TABLE` statement on p. 518.

Comment: Thanks very much, Tom and Matt, for your time and help. Sorry it took so long to respond. I guess I will stick with the Progress documentation. Lots of info out there for 'migrating' Progress to SQL Server - not so much for bringing over a few bits and pieces 